# convert RGB arrays to PIL image

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

In my code, I am creating a RGB array (256 * 256 * 3) and I need to show it.
I am having trouble creating a PIL image from a RGB array.
I wrote this code to explain:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('img_test.png')
image.thumbnail((256, 256))
image = image.convert("RGB")
image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32) / 255

PIL.Image.fromarray(image, "RGB").show()
```

I am getting this image back:

[image]

If I am using

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Then I am getting this image:
[image]

What am I doing wrong with this line?

```py
PIL.Image.fromarray(image, "RGB").show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are expecting PIL to handle a 32-bit floating point RGB image, which it cannot - see [here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

It can handle, amongst others:

- RGB as three 8-bit integer values (RGB888), or
- greyscale float32.

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
Image.fromarray(np.array(img).astype(np.uint8).transpose(1,2,0))
```

Comment: it was the `.astype(np.uint8)` that fixed the problem for me - my image was sized H x W x C

Comment: And I think the reverse transpose operation is `.transpose(2,0,1)` when using `np.asarray(img)`

Answer (score 1):

The line you mention seems fine, however, I wonder why you do this:

```py
image = np.asarray(image, dtype=np.float32) / 255
```

If you replace that line by the following, it works for me, using either PIL or matplotlib to show the image:

```py
image = np.asarray(image)
```